# Disable widgets in customizer for sidebar

Tags: customization, widgets

Please tell me how to customizer disable (hide) the sidebar widget for sidebar?
That is when we choose to customizer sidebar - We show only a specific set of widgets.

I created my sidebar, for which only certain widgets to be applied. In customizer need to hide the widgets are not suitable for my sidebar.